# validation with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

The following jQuery validation works well, however there is sth wrong within the AJAX call as it return unsuccessful. Full code here http://jsfiddle.net/YJwsZ/6/

I am quite new with AJAX as well.

I would like the following to return successful:

```
// AJAX call
$.ajax({
    url:url_site,
    data : data,
    // dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    success: function(r){
        if (r.success) {
            alert('success');
        }
        else {
            alert('unsuccessful');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: try to add  textStatus on your  function(r,textStatus), then alert it

Answer (score 1):

Try to rebuild your ajax call and add the success callback as a chained function. You also might want to create a little php script that actually answers your testcase. See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)!

http://jsfiddle.net/VyFng/1/

```
$.ajax({
    url: url_site,
    data: data,
    // dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
}).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    alert(textStatus);
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(textStatus);
})
.always(function(dataOrJqXHR, textStatus, jqXHRorErrorThrown) {
    alert('callback after ' + textStatus + ' callback has been completed');
});
```

Comment: when I try locally it return success when clicking on submit even though all the fields are empty...

Answer (score 0):

It's probably unsuccessful because **url_site** is not setup correctly.  Re-check your path to the file you are trying to connect to.  Use an absolute path if you just can't get a relative location working for you.

Comment: From the example given... `var url_site = location.href` - it's submitting to itself.

Comment: why are you trying to use ajax to load the same page you are on?

Comment: eventually this form will be part of a bigger page so I will need it to refresh by sending a successful or unsuccessful message...

Comment: Here is one way to handle that specific situation.  You can check against the form field values with either a jQuery submit, change, or blur method.  Have the validation statements already on your html page, but hidden. And when the user submits invalid data, display the validation message.  So your not "sending" a successful or unsuccessful message, but simply revealing the appropriate message based on the user's input.  You could then use ajax, to send data to that same page where your form is at, after the user completes the form.